# Rounded Corners within HTML

Tags: html, layout

I'm working on an app whose background is black. The main content area will be a white area. The white area will have rounded corners. For the past couple of years, this app has relied on a single large table. This table had cells that had an image that was created to represent the rounded corners. I'm in the process of updating this app and I wanted to use a more respectable approach. For that reason, I'm seeking some feedback. Basically, my site looks like this:

```
                         tab1 | tab2 | tab3
[corner]----------------       --------------------[corner]
   |                                                   |
   |                                                   |
   |                                                   |
   |                                                   |
   |                                                   |
  ...                                                 ...
   |                                                   |
[corner]-------------------------------------------[corner]
```

I started the update of this app with ASP.NET MVC 4. The template has the following:

```
<body>
    <header>
    ...
    <header>

    <div id="body">
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>
 </body>
```

In my limited opinion, I felt the upper left/right corners should go in the `<header>` and the lower left/right corners should go in the `<footer>`. If i do that, I'm not sure how to make it all line up though. I appreciate any recommendations or code samples anyone can provide. I'm struggling to get this all to line up.

Thank you!

Comment: What you're looking for is CSS, or cascading style sheets. CSS allows you to format your HTML markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `border-radius` css property to achieve the affect of rounded corners. For the header for example you might have

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

[Excellent article here](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) and [Browser Support here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools has a great reference here: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp
I also made a tutorial myself: http://www.andytechguy.com/tutorials/css/how-to-make-round-corners-css/